# Importing Oracle12c database

Tags: oracle, import, oracle-12c, sqlplus

i am using Oracle 12c in debian Jessie 
i want to import an old database exported with expdp on oracle 12c
when i try to launch the commande 'impdp' i got those errors :
'ORA-39002: invalid operation'
'ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file'
'ORA-39087: directory name DUMPS is invalid'
Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your oracle directory doesn't exists. You will need to log into the database, create a directory, and retry your import

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/path/to/oracle/home
export ORACLE_SID=YOUR_SID    
sqlplus / as sysdba
create directory DUMPS as '/path/to/your/dump/files';
exit;
```

And retry your import. Pending on the user you are using to do the import, you may need to grant read/write access.

Comment: You may want to mark your other post as answered as well, if this is the same issue.